# Django run function when session expires

Tags: django, session

i know that i can set the session to expire when user close the browser, and this is good. now i need a next step.
The problem is this:
The can start an action by clicking the button "start". This creates a tuple which is sotred in the database. This has a field called "status" that is set to IN PROGRESS. 
When the user push the button "end" i change the value of the status to FINISHED

Now, if between the "start" and "end" the user close the browser the session expires. 
What i want to do is to being able to intercept that the session is expired and remove the tuple from the database.

Basically what i want to do is run a function when session expires.

Answer (score 0):

The session 'expires' by having the cookie on the browser expire, so your django server won't actually know when this occurs.

What I would do in your case, is delete the old data in a cron or celery job periodically.

Comment: does not exists something like listeners in java?
Basically something that tells me when user close the browser?

Comment: @EsseTi that doesn't exist in Java, either.

Comment: @EsseTi Django runs on the server, and the browser doesn't tell the server when it closes a window, so no matter what server side framework/language you're using, there's no way to know other than to guess by inactivity.

Comment: @DanielRoseman what about HttpSessionListener? what i need is smt like that.

Comment: @EsseTi I believe that works by periodically checking to see if the session is expired, and calling the callback if it is expired, and deleting the session at the same time

Comment: any possibility to do a periodical check in django?

Comment: Either a standard unix cron job, combined with a django command, or celery are the two approaches I've used in the past